# How to leave in-app-billing-purchase within a class

Tags: java, android, in-app-billing

I already have in my application the integration with "in-app-billing-purchase" however I have several activity where I need to be duplicating all the code.

So I thought about leaving everything focused on a single class, I wastancio the class and I arrive if the item was bought.

Just that I have a big problem the "in-app-billing-purchase" uses Listener `OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener` and `QueryInventoryFinishedListener`

How can I leave all this organized in a single class and just check with a simple call in my activity?

**Calling code:**

```
Billing bl = new Billing(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
if (bl.Comprado())
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Comprado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
else
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Erro comprado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

**Class I created to be called multiple times**

```
public class Billing {
// Item name for premium status
private static final String SKU_PREMIUM = "premium";
// private static final String SKU_PREMIUM = "tirarbanner";
// Flag set to true when we have premium status
private static boolean mIsPremium = false;
// In-app Billing helper
private IabHelper mAbHelper;

public Billing(Context context) {

    String base64EncodedPublicKey = "xxx";
    // Create in-app billing helper
    mAbHelper = new IabHelper(context, base64EncodedPublicKey);
    // and start setup. If setup is successfull, query inventory we already
    // own
    mAbHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
        public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {

            if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                return;
            }
            mAbHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mGotInventoryListener);
        }
    });
}

public static boolean Comprado() {
    return mIsPremium;
}

/**
 * Listener that is called when we finish purchase flow.
 */
IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
    public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase) {

        if (result.isFailure()) {
            return;
        }
        // Purchase was successfull, set premium flag and update interface
        if (purchase.getSku().equals(SKU_PREMIUM)) {
            mIsPremium = true;
        }
    }
};

/**
 * Listener that's called when we finish querying the items and
 * subscriptions we own
 */
IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
    public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {

        // Have we been disposed of in the meantime? If so, quit.
        if (mAbHelper == null)
            return;

        // Is it a failure?
        if (result.isFailure()) {
            return;
        }

        // Do we have the premium upgrade?
        Purchase premiumPurchase = inventory.getPurchase(SKU_PREMIUM);
        mIsPremium = premiumPurchase != null;

    }
};
```

}

Answer (score 0):

There's already a library for that.

Check [android-inapp-billing-v3.](https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3)

Comment: But I already use the library, what I need and instead of using the same code to centralize everything in my class